# Why does the minimum exist in optimal transport?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $P,Q$ be any two distributions and let $\mathcal{M}(P,Q)$  be the set of all couplings of $P$ and $Q.$ For a given metric $d(\cdot,\cdot),$ the optimal transport cost is:

$$\min_{(X,Y)\sim M\in \mathcal{M}(P,Q)} \mathbb{E}d(X,Y)~.$$

Why is the minimizing coupling guaranteed to exist for $P,Q$ being distributions over some general space? This quantity frequently appears in the book Concentration Inequalities by Boucheron, Lugosi, Massart (Chapter: The Transportation Method). Yet, no argument is provided as to why the minimizer of the transportation cost must exist.

Comment: Usually this is done via the "direct method of calculus of variations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimizer exists, whenever the set of couplings $\mathcal{M}(P,Q)$ is weak* compact. It is the case when $P,Q \ $are distributions over a [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space). See [Optimal transport, old and new](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf) by Cedric Villani, theorem 4.1.